# How do I programmatically add cell style to a cell using tableView.dequeueReusableCell?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am doing a programmatic Swift app and can't find a way to add **style: .subtitle** to the cell when I am using tableView.dequeueReusableCell.

In the following code I want to be able to set the style to .subtitle:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        
    ...
        
    return cell
}
```

I tried adding the following but it cannot be used in conjunction with dequeue:

```
var cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

What is the correct way to add this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass `UITableViewCell`, and override `init(style:reuseIdentifier:)`:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
}
```

then, register this class with the table view:

```
tableView.register(MyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
```